# SUM of VLOOKUP functions meeting criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office

Sorry for the macabre subject matter, but I need to add the ages up of a group of people IF they have died.

My data is structured as follows:

- Sheet A has the list of people to analyze.
- Sheet B is an essential database of all people, with a Yes/No column for if they are alive, and another column for their age.

Basically, I want to get the `SUM` of ages of the people on a list on Sheet A IF the person is dead.

In my head, it combines the `VLOOKUP`, `SUM` and `IF` functions, but not quite sure how. I want the result in ONE cell.

Thanks for any suggestions!

For formula matters, let's assume the data is structured as below, with the highlighted cell where I want the formula to say 60:

[image: Sheet A]

[image: Sheet B]

Comment: You want SUMIF() or SUMIFS()

Comment: Can you review the screenshots I just added and let me know if you could come up with a formula or methodology to use those functions? I am drawing a blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the data structure you provided if you only want to sum the names in Group 1 that are dead then you would use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(E:E,F:F,"No",D:D,B1:B3))
```

[image]

If the Names are not important then use @JoeJam's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `=SUMIF(C2:C4,"No",B2:B4)` where the age is in column B and Yes/No is in column C.